# Socks Server Behind HTTP Proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, socks

I have a notebook(let's call it NOTEBOOK A) that is connected to INTERNAL NETWORK A. In order to browse the internet, NOTEBOOK A connects to a HTTP PROXY server which also resides in INTERNAL NETWORK A.

A second notebook (NOTEBOOK B), does not have the wifi password to access INTERNAL NETWORK A. So, NOTEBOOK B wants to access INTERNET and use NOTEBOOK A as tunnel. NOTEBOOK B successfuly established a network connection to NOTEBOOK A thru blueooth's Network Service.

NOTEBOOK A installed FreeProxy Software and hosted as a SOCKS server, which is for NOTEBOOK B to tunnel over. NOTEBOOK B then set its firefox to use SOCKS proxy and point to NOTEBOOK A. NOTEBOOK B managed to browse all the websites resides in INTERNAL NETWORK A, but the problem now is it can't browse the internet.

So, question is, how to configure the HTTP proxy for NOTEBOOK B? or it's suppose to handle by the SOCKS SERVER side?

Comment: set up internet connection sharing (or similar) on notebook A and connect directly to the proxy with notebook B.

Answer (score 0):

Rather get notebook A to provide access to the proxy server with a DNAT iptables rule, and configure notebook B to use that instead of SOCKS.